# How can I extract fitted line slope coefficients in Spotfire?

Tags: visualization, linear-regression, spotfire, intercept

I have set up a trellis visualization in Spotfire showing line charts for my data. I've also added a "Straight Line Fit" in the "Lines & Curves" tab of the properties

[image: see image for my current setup].

Does anyone know how to access those coefficients of intercept and slope? I would like to sort my visualizations with the slope (most- to least-negative) information calculated.

I'm using the Spotfire 7.6.0.57 build. Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean "sort your visualization"? Since you are using a Date on the Category Axis, this would have to change.

Comment: By sort, I mean arrange those charts seen in the trellis in order of increasing slope. So, the worst performer would be in the upper left, the second worst in the upper right, the third worst in the middle row left, etc.

Even if I can't rearrange the placement of charts this way, just knowing how to access the slope or intercept of these fitted lines would be great!

Answer (score 2):

Go to the 'Straight Line Fit' in 'Lines & Curves' of the properties, select it and go to 'More'. From there you can export the coefficients to a text file, re-import it and link it's columns to the original data table.
[Exporting the coefficients of a curve fit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZ5lR.png)

Answer (score 1):

There is another option using IronPython if you want to build on the fits already computed by Spotfire and shown in the chart (based on [this](https://spotfired.blogspot.com/2015/10/extract-values-from-curve.html)). This avoids running yet another fit in R and extracting those (potentially slightly different) fit results, which in my case (very large data set) was a real time saver. The same would probably work for line charts I reckon. So register an IronPython script and adjust the below code to your page and visualzation titles:

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import ScatterPlot, FittingModels

# grab the fitting model of the first (counting starts at 0!) lines & curves item and export to data table
for page in Document.Pages:  #Loop through every page
    if page.Title == 'Your Page Title':  #find the right page
        for viz in page.Visuals:  #On this page, loop through every viz         
            if viz.Title == 'Your Scatter Plot Title':  #find the right viz             
                ScatterPlot=viz.As[ScatterPlot]()               
                ScatterPlot.FittingModels[0].Enabled=True # [0] is the first fit in the list of fits in the lines & curves section of the properties menue
                ds = ScatterPlot.FittingModels[0].GetResultsDataSource()
                if Document.Data.Tables.Contains("Curve Fit Results"):
                    table=Document.Data.Tables["Curve Fit Results"]
                    table.ReplaceData(ds)
                else:
                    Document.Data.Tables.Add("Curve Fit Results", ds)
```

The result will be an additional data table called [Curve Fit Results] wich (in case of a straight line fit) holds intercept a, slope b and R² for each straight line fit. You can e.g. tie this script to an action control in a text area to trigger it.

Answer (score 0):

When doing the straight line fit, there should be a data table created with a name like `YourDataTable_Straight line`. The regressed coefficients will be there.

Answer (score 0):

With a r script you are able to get the coefficients into a data frame. I've used this one, for exactly that issue:

```
tb.lm <- lm(y ~ x, data = yourtable)
tb.summary.lm <- summary(tb.lm)
df <- as.data.frame(tb.summary.lm$coefficients)

row.names(df)=c("intercept","slope")
coef <- data.frame(yourColumnname = row.names(df),df)
```

Where `coef` will be your output, as a table in your spotfire analysis.

I've reached to this after reading this:
[Linear-Regression](http://r-statistics.co/Linear-Regression.html)

and this:
[TIBCO support](https://support.tibco.com/s/article/Data-function-returns-Error-in-as-data-frame-default-cannot-coerce-class-summary-lm-into-a-data-frame)